# How can I cleanly perform a sync operation after the completion of an async thunk

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Within a react component, I would like to dispatch an asynchronous action, then when it is complete, dispatch a synchronous action that depends on values added by the asynchronous action. Using redux-thunk, so far, I have:

```
/* actionCreators.js */
export function refresh() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return services.getData().then(response => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        dispatch(addData(response.data))
        resolve()
      })
    })
  }
}

/* myComponent.js */
refreshData = id => {
  this.props.dispatch(refresh(id)).then(() => {
  this.props.handleChange(id)
  })
}
```

This is actually working, but it seems like a lot of nested code, and I am wondering if there is a more standard way to juggle this async.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall strategy on performing logic after an async action completes is correct, you need to return a promise from the thunk and then use `then()` elsewhere to hook into the completion.

That said, the first change you can make to help slim down the code is related to the Promise constructor. You can change the `refresh()` implementation into

```
export function refresh() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return services.getData().then(response => {
            return dispatch(addData(response.data));
        }
    }
}
```

This is because the type of `.then()` on a `Promise<T>` is `then<S>(callback: T => S): Promise<S>`, meaning that the outcome of calling `then` is another promise, so there is no need for you to construct your own.

Further, it looks like you are mixing both the standard `function` syntax with the fat arrow (`=>`) syntax, when being consistent and using `=>` everywhere can also help slim down your code:

```
export const refresh = () =>
    dispatch => services.getData()
        .then(response => dispatch(addData(response.data));

/* myComponent.js */
refreshData = id => this.props.dispatch(refresh(id))
    .then(() => this.props.handleChange(id));
```

Comment: I did try simply to return `dispatch`, but since it is a sync redux action, there was no promise to return. That is why i wrapped it in a promise. Maybe i missed something :/